ELIFECYCLE. Project just randomly crashed
I`ve made a project for my own purpose (to-do list + communication with Telegram bot)
I finished my work yesterday without any error, any major change in files etc. and i just can run "npm start" now.
Here is my logs:
app.set('port', port);
    ^

TypeError: app.set is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\todoloveapp\bin\www:16:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todoloveapp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the todoloveapp@0.0.0 start script.

Tried to do every solution from Google (clean cache, delete node_modules and package.json.lock and force install) and it`s not working.
I know, maybe it`s small problem but i really wants to continue my programming adventure!
EDIT:
Beggining of the app.js:
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const app = express();

Bottom of the app.js:
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000.');
});


Can you share a [mcve]? Specifically, what is app and how is it initialized?

Share the code of you main file i.e. index.js/app.js.

@Mureinik @Subha
I just added this line at the bottom of the app.js:
"module.exports = app;"
And it is working now, but...
Why my project is working well on a hosting without this line, but on local envoirment it is keep crashing?
